# PHP include inconsistently working

Tags: php, include

I have always had problems with PHP's include function. I'm making a shop website and i've created a shopping cart. I want it in each the sidebar of a few pages so i'm using include.

in the file /public_html/product/index.php on line 37:
     `include("converter.php");`

the file converter.php is at /public_html/include/converter.php

At times it seems to work but most of the time it displays:

> Warning: include(converter.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public_html/product/index.php on line 37

and then

> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'converter.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/a3371827/public_html/product/index.php on line 37

Am I missing something about include??

Answer (score 5):

Wrong path.  Use this:

```
include("../include/converter.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a directory path issue. try using `include_once("../include/converter.php");` or debug further using `print getcwd();` and then use `chdir();` to set correct the path.

edit: missed the folderpath in your question, fixd

Comment: So I read the path wrong twice, 23:30, should be sleeping, not browsing SO. :)

Comment: Now its fixed :) -> deleted my previous comment. Your one hour ahead of me (22:30 local time), so I got another 60 minutes wasting time on SO *gg*

Answer (score -1):

The file your looking for is not (directly or indirectly) under any of the paths listed in your include_path . That's why does not work.

Comment: ? Why the downvote? The include_path does not contain `/home/a3371827/public_html/include` .

Comment: didnt downvote, but… actually you are only stating the obvious (file not there) without giving a concrete solution like Brad did. Although I think a downvote is a bit harsh.

Comment: @Max : The question is "Did I miss something?". The OP wants to understand `include`: he says "I have always had problems with PHP's include function" And the answer who got (for now) 5 upvotes does not even explain why it did not work. What's wrong with the voters?